# ExpressionLanguage (EL) Not Working as expected

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el

I am creating web application where I have below code.

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" 
 style="#{patentInfo.photoType.contains('application')?
 'visibility:visible;width:200px;height:200px;
  background-image: url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&amp;id=#{patentInfo.photoType});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;'
 :
 'visibility:hidden;width:2px;height:2px;'}">
```

I am setting background image where I am using Java class as `DisplayImage` and passing parameter to those as `mainID=tempo1&amp;id=#{patentInfo.photoType}`. In java, I am printing `mainID` & `id` for testing purpose.

**DipalyImage.java**

```
String mainID = request.getParameter("mainID");
String id = request.getParameter("id");
System.out.println("mainID=="+mainID+", id=="+id);
```

`patentInfo.photoType` will hold data as `application/pdf`

***The problem is at background image parameters that I am passing.***

1. When I use `background-image: url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&amp;id=#{patentInfo.photoType});` & print `mainID` & `id` I get values as below.

   `mainID=temp1` & `id=`

   I don't get anything for id.....
2. When I use `background-image: url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&amp;id=patentInfo.photoType);` & print `mainID` & `id` I get values as below.

   `mainID=temp1` & `id=patentInfo.photoType`

What I am doing wrong here?

I am expecting output as `mainID=temp1` & `id=application/pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `#{ ... #{} ...}` in your el.

Try something like this:

`<p:commandButton ajax="false" style="#{patentInfo.photoType.contains('application')?'visibility:visible;width:200px;height:200px;background-image: url(DisplayImage?mainID=tempo1&amp;id='.concat(patentInfo.photoType).concat(';background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%;'):'visibility:hidden;width:2px;height:2px;'}">`

Comment: not working... Error is `javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /showThumbnailss.xhtml @51,378`

Comment: Oh. I overlooked the : Updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I found the same later. BUT, now image is not coming and Java section is not getting called... Not sure why :(

Comment: I got the problem... You was missing `)` before `;background-repeat` (you was not closing URL

Comment: Thanks a TON man... You saved me!!! And learned how to use concat here...  I used to use concat in EXCEL but not here... Thanks a ton again...